# Universal Android Music Player - Songs (Grouped) by Title

Tags: java, android

This is in relation to the [android-UniversalMusicPlayer Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) on GitHub.

I managed to create a list of songs (grouped by title) by using the following in MusicService.java (along with the other, and unmentioned, methods):

```
...
List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem> mediaItems = new ArrayList<>();
...
// Song titles root view
        if (MEDIA_ID_ROOT.equals(parentMediaId)) {
            LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren.ROOT");
            mediaItems.add(new MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem(
                    new MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder()
                            .setMediaId(MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_TITLE)
                            .setTitle(getString(R.string.browse_song_titles))
                            .setIconUri(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +
                                    getPackageName() + "/drawable/ic_by_title"))
                            .setSubtitle(getString(R.string.browse_song_titles_subtitle))
                            .build(), MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE
            ));

        }
...
// Other lists
```

And then a child list with descriptions like this:

```
// Other lists

else if (MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_TITLE.equals(parentMediaId)) {
            LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren.TITLES");
            for (String title : mMusicProvider.getSongTitles()) {
                for (MediaMetadataCompat track : mMusicProvider.getMusicsBySongTitle(title)) {
                    String hierarchyAwareMediaID = MediaIDHelper.createMediaID(
                            track.getDescription().getMediaId(), MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_TITLE, title);
                    MediaMetadataCompat trackCopy = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder(track)
                            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID, hierarchyAwareMediaID)
                            .build();
                    MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem bItem = new MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem(
                            trackCopy.getDescription(), MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem.FLAG_PLAYABLE);
                    mediaItems.add(bItem);
                }
            }

        }
// More lists
```

But the problem with this approach is that while it does generate the list, the onPlayFromMusicID call will only find that individual item in the list.

Is there a way to implement a song list (grouped by song titles) that is only one level deep (meaning -> Open App, Select Songs > [all_songs] get listed - then tapping on one of them will play and continue the playlist from that position) while allowing the QueueHelper.java to be able to build a play list as well?

Comment: @nagesh-susaria I hope you see this~

Comment: IIUC, you want to shorten the hierarchy from select -> title -> all songs to select -> all songs. Is that right? If so then its possible by adding all the items on the top level. Note that you'd have to build your own hierarchy aware mediaId. If all songs are only ever getting listed as title, then you can use the mediaId.

Comment: Got it - so expand the mediaID to account for the shorter hierarchy level.